# Probability of picking yellow after red.

Tags: probability

I have a bag with $8$ red apples, $4$ green apples, and $5$ yellow apples.

I select two apples without replacement, what is the probability that the second apple is yellow if the first is red?

$P(\text{2nd apple is yellow} \mid \text{1st apple is red}) = \:?$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

If the first is red, then there are 7 remaining red apples, 4 green, and 5 yellow.

Hence:  $P$(2nd is yellow|first is red) = ${5 \over 16}$.